# Changed position from day and month converting strings to date

Tags: php

I am working on following issue in PHP.
I have these variables:

$fecha = "01-07-2017";

$hora = "11:30";

Now I want to create a date variable with format Y-m-d H:i.

For that I am using following code:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($fecha.' '.$hora));
```

But I am getting the output:

```
echo $newDate = 2017-01-07 11:30
```

I need it to be: 2017-07-01 11:30

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php) API to parse your string(s) initially

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $fecha.' '.$hora);
$newDt = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/827662

Comment: thank you Phil, it works, but I need to assign the output to a variable. I have tried: $newDt = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i'); But it doesn´t work.

Comment: I need to store the output in a datetime field in MySQL table. What should I do?

Comment: @mvasco `$newDt = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i')` should definitely work. The `format` call just returns a string. I've updated the demo

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to:

```
$newDate = date("Y-d-m H:i", strtotime($fecha.' '.$hora));
```

Notice that I just switched around 'h' & 'd' in the date function.

Comment: All you're doing here is swapping the day and month in the **output**. The parsed date is still incorrect for OP's purposes

Comment: Thanks Difster, the answer from Phil is correct, but I need now to store the output value to a datetime field in a MySQL table.